# ExoPlayer getDuration

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying to play mp3 file from URL with `ExoPlayer`.

Everything is fine, but now I wonder when is the it is safe to call `getDuration()` of the audio track. I just need it once the track is loaded. I didn't find it in Google's example project.

When I try to get it immediately after `exoPlayer.prepare()` then I get `UNKNOWN_TIME`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, looks like this is the only solution here.

We add listener to our player, and get duration when state changes to `STATE_READY`. It will obviously called on every play/pause action so we need to wrap it with `boolean durationSet` flag `if` check to call it once on track start. Then `durationSet = false` somewhere near `audioPlayer.prepare()`

```
audioPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY && !durationSet) {
                long realDurationMillis = audioPlayer.getDuration();
                durationSet = true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {
            // No op.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            // No op.
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am trying ExoPlayer playback of .mp3 and .aac files. I get duration for mp3 but not for aac. What can I try? Where might I be wrong?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777975/not-able-to-get-getduration-for-aac-file-using-exoplayer

Comment: Thank you! I think the new version of exoplayer users: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.EventListener.html if you want to update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
private int getVideoDurationSeconds(SimpleExoPlayer player)
    {
        int timeMs=(int) player.getDuration();
        int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;
        return totalSeconds;
    }
```

just call this method with exoplayer object and you will find total seconds

**complete method**

```
private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
    StringBuilder mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());
    int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;
  //  videoDurationInSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the duration, after the media is prepared and loaded in exoplayer, call `exoPlayer.getDuration()` which returns the duration in milliseconds.

note that if the media is liveStream or duration is not available, it will return `C.TIME_UNSET`.

you can also customize the duration for your self if you're showing Ad.
telegram android project is doing something like this:

```
@Override
  public long getDuration() {
    if (isPlayingAd()) {
      MediaPeriodId periodId = playbackInfo.periodId;
      playbackInfo.timeline.getPeriodByUid(periodId.periodUid, period);
      long adDurationUs = period.getAdDurationUs(periodId.adGroupIndex, periodId.adIndexInAdGroup);
      return C.usToMs(adDurationUs);
    }
    return getContentDuration();
  }
```

here is the source code to [telegram android project](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram).

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of **pavelkorolevxyz**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35430587/9851608) works well if you have a single media item in the track, but if there are multiple items/files, it would be a cumbersome to get around the `if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY && !durationSet)` condition and to reset the `durationSet` for the new media file.

We'd better change that by Media3 ExoPlayer API `onMediaItemTransition()` callback for the upcoming media files:

```
var mediaDuration = 0L // inital value is 0 before starting the player
val listener = object : Player.Listener {

    override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
        if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY && mediaDuration == 0) {
            // The player is just run, and this is the 1st MediaItem duration
            mediaDuration = exoPlayer.duration
        }
    }
    
    override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
        super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
       
        // Media Transition, this is another mediaItem beyond the first one
        mediaDuration = exoPlayer.duration
        
    }
}

// register the listener 
exoPlayer.addListener(listener)
```

Then you could reset `mediaDuration = 0L` when releasing the player resources.

Answer (score 0):

The duration is not available immediately, but as soon as its available, the timeline is updated.

From [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer/playlists#detecting-playlist-change):

> When information such as the duration of a media item in the playlist becomes available, the `Timeline` will be updated and `onTimelineChanged` will be called with `TIMELINE_CHANGE_REASON_SOURCE_UPDATE`.

```kotlin
override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, reason: Int) {
    if (reason == Player.TIMELINE_CHANGE_REASON_SOURCE_UPDATE) {
        // duration is available now:
        // player.duration
    }            
}
```